# Convergence of series with $\sin(\sqrt{n})/n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Here is a series, a friend of mine gave me.

Examine the convergence of the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{n})}{n}.$$
It is from the book *A Garden of Integrals, Frank E. Burk*. It is given after the chapter "The Euler Summation Formula". So I am interested in a solution, which avoids this formula, and is, say, more *elementary* in terms of the tools it uses. Thank you!

**EDIT**. Thanks for pointing out the earlier question. Sorry that I did not look up. The solution there is very nice. If you find any other solutions, please post them.